# How to use named colors in wxpython?

Tags: python, user-interface, colors, wxpython

I get named colours in `wx` this way:

```
import wx.lib.colourdb as wb
wb.getColourList()
```

Although "ORANGE" is in `wx.lib.colourdb`, i cannot set a grid cell's color to `wx.ORANGE` because it says:

```
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'ORANGE'
```

How do I use the colors defined in `wx.lib.colourdb.getColourList()` ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
color = wx.NamedColour("orange")

some_window.SetForegroundColour("orange")
```

(make sure you start your app first)

in order to load some of the colours into `wx.TheColourDatabase` you will need to run

```
wx.lib.colourdb.updateColourDB()  #adds ALOT more named colours to wx.TheColourDatabase
c1 = wx.NamedColour("light coral")
c2 = wx.NamedColour("peachpuff2")
```

Comment: Thanks, but some colors don't work, such as "PEACHPUFF2", "LIGHTCORAL". They give white color. What might be the problem?

Comment: Thank you sir. Though it seems silly to update colourdb to add more colours. why arent those colors added by default?

Comment: I think they just add the most common ones by default

Answer (score 2):

I am just learning how to use the colour database too and ran across this thread while poking around looking for hints and examples. So now you know I'm no expert on this topic but I'll share what I've discovered so far.

1. I don't think you need to do *wx.lib.colourdb.updateColourDB()*. I don't use it and for me the database seems to be populated already. On my Ubuntu 12.04 system with wxPy 2.8.?, the database is initialised to 630 colors without that command.  If use the wx.lib.colourdb.updateColourDB() command and then count the colors I still get only 630 colors. If I print the list of color names the list seems to have the same colors in it regardless of whether I issue the wx.lib.colourdb.updateColourDB() command or not.
2. I too had a problem with colors being all white but I was trying to access the colors via incrementing an index in a for loop. I'm writing an app that makes 2D pie charts was trying to assign colors to the canvas brush in order to flood fill the pie sectors with **different** colors. I used the first 6 colors in the list (for a 6 sector pie) and found the whole pie was white. Eventually I looked at the color list (DuHHH!) and found the problem... the first 7 or so colors are all just slightly different shades of white and so similar to each other they appear to be exactly the same color.

I discovered 2 different solutions to this "everything is white" problem. The first solution involves shuffling the list of colors with Python's random.shuffle(sequence).

```
    import wx
    from random import shuffle, seed
    from wx.lib.colourdb import getColourList

    class MyFrame(wx.Frame):
            def __init__(self, parent, id, title):
            wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent, id, title, size=(1000, 1000))

            # COMMENT 1  wx.lib.colourdb.updateColourDB()

            i = 0
            self.colors = []
            for c in getColourList():
                print c,
                self.colors.append(c)
                print self.colors[i]
                i += 1
            print 'Counted', i, 'colors'
            seed()                           # seed the randomizer
            shuffle(self.colors)    
            exit()
```

Try something like the above first with the first comment as it is and then with it uncommented.  I think you will find the list printed in the for loop will be exactly the same in both cases.

Further down in my application I run a loop to draw the pie sectors on the wx.PaintDC. I can do it 2 different ways depending on whether I shuffle the list of colors. Shuffling distributes the white(ish) colors randomly throughout the list so all of the sectors fill with different colors. Here's the relevant part of the code.

```
    dc = wx.PaintDC(self.panel)
    for i in range(sector_count):
        dc.SetBrush(wx.Brush(self.colors[i]))
        DrawNextPieSector(dc)
```

The other solution I found was to **not** shuffle the color list and instead multiply the loop index by a constant in the brush assignment as follows.

```
        dc.SetBrush(wx.Brush(self.colors[i * 10]))
```

The above statement selects every 10th color which means the first sector will always be white but the others will be various other colors.

Shuffling the list takes about 2 secs on my old computer but it's slow.  Every time the app runs the sectors are different colors than they were in the previous run.  That may be desirable or it may not, depends what the app is supposed to do.

I want the sectors to be the same color every time the app runs because the end user wants to associate a particular color with a particular dataset.  For that reason I use the second approach. It's faster but it limits the app to 63 colors if the index multiplier is 10 as in the above example. I suppose I could modify the loop a bit and change the multiplier every 6th iteration or something like that but 63 colors is sufficient for me.